# Texliveonfly is not relocatable so it isn't being installed by tlmgr

Tags: packages, texlive, texmaker, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to be able to use texliveonfly with Texmaker. However when I use `sudo tlmgr install texliveonfly`I get an error saying it's not relocatable and hence I cannot install it in usermode. Please suggest some way to solve this problem. I'm new to LaTeX so please be detailed with your answers. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! If you are using Ubuntu's TeX Live, then you cannot use this script with `sudo`, I think, because the version of `tlmgr` you have is not standard but is, instead, a cut-down version which only supports installation on a user-level. You could try without `sudo` but I suspect the script may be too dependent on an standard installation. (But I always just install TeX Live, so I've never used this.)

Comment: I tried it without sudo but it still did not work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That is kind of what I expected :(. Distro's disable `tlmgr` management of the TL installation itself because they are using the system's standard package manager (`apt` or `yum` or `pacman` or whatever). If they did not, the managers would compete for control and the databases would not reflect the state of the system. So they have to do it. But it has disadvantages. This is one reason that installing from upstream is generally recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `tlmgr` in Debian/Ubuntu switches automatically into user mode. This is also issued every time `tlmgr` is started.

In user mode, only packages that are located completely in `texmf-dist` can be installed, since there is no way to know where to install binaries/scripts.

A future version of `tlmgr` might cater to this, but this is far from complete.

Solutions are now as follows:

- ask the sysadm to install all of TeX Live and by this also the requested script,
- install upstream TeX Live locally in your home directory
- download the `texonthefly` package and copy the files manually into `TEXMFHOME` and the scripts into `~/bin`

Hope that helps